# Implementing interface with inherited type in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

How can I create addWorker in interface? OfficeWorker inherits from Worker and now I want to make interface for few Workers. I don't know how to do it correct. void addWorker(Worker worker)  and void addWorker(Worker worker) are wrong.

**Interface**

```
public interface TypeOfWorker {        
    void addWorker(Worker worker);
}
```

**OfiiceWorker**

```
public class OfiiceWorker extends Worker implements TypeOfWorker {
    private int officeID;
    private int intelectl;
    private List<OfiiceWorker> ofiiceWorkers = new ArrayList<>();

    public OfiiceWorker(String name, String surname, int age, int experience, String street, int building,
            int local, String city, int officeID, int intelectl) {
        super(name, surname, age, experience, street, building, local, city);
        this.officeID = officeID;
        this.intelectl = intelectl;
    }

    @Override
    public void addWorker(OfiiceWorker ofiiceWorker) {
        ofiiceWorkers.add(ofiiceWorker);
    }
}
```

**Worker**

```
public abstract class Worker {
    private int identifier;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private int experience;
    private String street;
    private int building;
    private int local;
    private String city;

    public Worker() {
    }

    public Worker(String name, String surname, int age, int experience, String street, int building, int local,
            String city) {
        setIdentifier();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.street = street;
        this.building = building;
        this.local = local;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setIdentifier() {
        this.identifier = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to achieve with your interface, otherwise it will be hard to help you. Also your current solution looks like a bad design, each instance of OfiiceWorker will hold a list of other instances. Why do you want this, shouldn't this list be in another class instead like some kind of Worker handler class.

Answer (score 2):

You should use generics to let compiler relax with your types. First make your interface generic:

```
public interface TypeOfWorker<T extends Worker> {
    void addWorker(T worker);
}
```

Then declare the generic type of your class:

```
public class OfiiceWorke extends Worker implements TypeOfWorker<OfiiceWorke> {
```

With these modifications the below is fine:

```
@Override
public void addWorker(OfiiceWorke worker) {
```